# Stretch audio without pitch shifting python

Tags: python, audio

I need to accelerate and deaccelerate an audio file with wav extension, currently I'm using librosa to do this, the problem is that when I stretch the audio, the pitch also change. I would like to know if there is a library that I can use that stretch the audio but doesn't change the pitch.
I'm doing something like this:

`y_fast = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, 1.5)`

Comment: voice or music?

Comment: It is voice recordings